# TypeError when using remote_create using Facebook Python Business SDK

Tags: python, facebook

I am currently getting this error (along with most recent calls) when trying to run the remote_create method in the Facebook Python Business SDK:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ad_creator.py", line 41, in <module>
campaign.remote_create()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebook_business/adobjects/abstractcrudobject.py", line 296, in remote_create
response = request.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebook_business/api.py", line 667, in execute
api_version=self._api_version,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebook_business/api.py", line 329, in call
if fb_response.is_failure():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebook_business/api.py", line 117, in is_failure
return not self.is_success()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/facebook_business/api.py", line 102, in is_success
    return json_body['success']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

It appears the error is being thrown from the api.py file in the API:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk/blob/master/facebook_business/api.py

My code (after creating a Facebook session), is the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    FacebookAdsApi.set_default_api(api)

    account = AdAccount(config['act_id'])

    print('**** Creating ad...')

    campaign = Campaign(parent_id=account)
    campaign.update({
        Campaign.Field.name: 'My First Campaign',
        Campaign.Field.objective: 'REACH',
    })

    campaign.remote_create()

    print(campaign)
```

Please help me figure out what's causing the TypeError.

Comment: Do you have `act_` prefix in your `config['act_id']`?

Comment: `Campaign(parent_id=account)` shouldn't it be `Campaign(parent_id=account.id)` instead?

Comment: @nutic yes, I do have the `act_` prefix.

Comment: @nutic if I `print(campaign)` directly before the line `campaign.remote_create()`, I see the following:
`<Campaign> {
    "name": "My First Campaign",
    "objective": "REACH"
}`

This leads me to believe that the campaign is being created correctly using `Campaign(parent_id=account)`

Comment: I found the issue. it should have been `campaign = Campaign(parent_id=account.get_id_assured())`.